# How to find a general solution of a canonical form?

Tags: calculus

I have worked out a canonical form of PDE, but do not know how to get the general solution.
Can anyone help, please?

$$  (\xi + \eta)^2 u_{\xi \eta} = 0  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

If the product of two things is zero, one or the other (or both) is zero.  Can you solve each of $(\xi + \eta)^2 = 0$ and $u_{\xi \eta} = 0$?

Comment: Thank you, Eric Towers. I haven't properly learned PDE yet. Yes, I can solve uξη=0, but not sure the first one.

Comment: This is an algebraic equation.  What is the only number whose square is zero?  So you know that $\xi + \eta = {}$ that number.

Comment: I am also thinking expand the brackets, ξ^2  u_ξη+2ξη u_ξη+η^2  u_ξη=0, then I stuck. It's quite frustrating when you don't know something.

Comment: ξ and η are functions of x and y

Comment: Break into three integral along the additions, then use integration by parts to reduce the powers of $\xi$ and $\eta$.  It's a mess...

Comment: Thank you. Eric Towers, I don't think I know the concept of PDE. Any book you can recommend, please?

Comment: @Newbee : I originally learned from Farlow's "Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers".  I don't know that I'd *recommend* that book, but it is a reasonable starting point.

Comment: Thank you, Eric Towers.